# jQuery, нажатая клавиша

Tags: jquery

Как в jQuery узнать какая клавиша нажата, получите ее значение?

Comment: Два вопроса:  
* клавиша мыши или клавиатуры?  
* зачем jQuery?

Comment: Клавиша клавитуры (числа и буквы), именно на jQuery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если уж очень хочется на jquery

```
$('#target').keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) { 
  // здесь 13 это код нажатой на клаве кнопки, 13 это ентер, ниже есть ссылка на страницу со всеми кодами и на какую клавишу они ведут

      //какое то действие которое происходит если нужная клавиша нажата
  }
}
```

если же вам нужен допустим crtl + enter то условие будет такое

```
if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 13)
```

коды кнопок [тут](http://web.archive.org/web/20121102150223/http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/What-is-the-list-of-KeyCodes-for-JavaScript-KeyDown-KeyPress-and-KeyUp-events.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно по экспериментировать. Некоторые клавиши удается отловить при помощи keydown, а некоторые только по keyup, здесь все зависит от браузера. Например, я очень часто сталкивался с ситуацией, когда нажимаешь TAB, в обработчик приходит keydown, а keyup уже прийдет к следующему контролу, на который переместится фокус ввода. Самые верный способ - повесить обработчики keydown, keyup, keypress на input и выводить коды клавиш (с которыми кстати тоже есть определенный гемор) вместе с названием события в консоль, чтобы разобраться какие коды куда приходят, и уже исходя из этого исследования вести разработку.

Answer (score 0):

Можно повесить обработчик на событие [keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)